# cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyTastTasklet'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am developing **Spring Boot Batch Example**. In this example, I have created BatchJPA core module which has Entities, JPARepository and DB configurations.

This module adding into another Spring Module as dependency and in this module, I am adding code related specific batch jobs (like custom repository etc). I have total 15 batch jobs and I will be creating separate Spring Boot project with BatchJPA dependency.

```
10-08-2018 14:54:11.853 [main] WARN  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyTestTasklet': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' available
10-08-2018 14:54:11.855 [main] INFO  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.logAutoConfigurationReport - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
10-08-2018 14:54:11.919 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter.report - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'transactionManager' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'transactionManager' in your configuration.
```

Code below:

```
@Service
public class MyTaskTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Autowired
    private MyCustomerCustomRepository myCustomerCustomRepository;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

        List<MyTest> mydata = myCustomerCustomRepository.getElligibleData();
        if (!mydata.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("XXXXXX = " + mydata.size());
        }

        chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext()
                .put("listOfData", mydata);

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Another file:

```
@Component
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobLauncher {

    public void executeJob() {
        String[] springConfig = { "jobs/ABC.xml"};

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("MyJobId");

        try {
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("runMode", "DATA")
                    .addDate("date", new Date()).addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
            jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and another file
**MainApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MainApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private MyJobLauncher jobLauncher;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyJobLauncher.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        jobLauncher.executeJob();
    }
}
```

Comment: `MyTestTasklet` is the file that's causing the problem, without the code for that one it's difficult to say what the problem is. Likely it is an autowiring issue, depending on what `transactionManager` is meant to be.

Comment: MyTestTasklet have already shown above, what else you need to guide me ?

Comment: The `@EnableBatchProcessing` should add a transaction manager to your context but it looks like it is not taken into account since you are loading your job from an XML file `jobs/ABC.xml`. I would move `@EnableBatchProcessing` on the `MainApplication` class and run the app with `SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);` instead of `SpringApplication.run(MyJobLauncher.class, args);`. Can you try that?

Comment: @prateek you’re not showing ‘MyTestTasklet’ you’re showing MyTaskTasklet.

Comment: You issue is that you are loading a new application context from `ABC.xml` in the `executeJob` method. This context is different from the one that will be loaded by Spring Boot on startup. So your missing transaction manager (and all other services) should be defined in that XML file unless you import other configuration classes from this file.

Comment: Could you please guide me what correct approach should be taken when wanted to use XML based approach for Spring Batch in Spring boot ?